# 404 error while searching for twilio available phone number

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio trial account to know the compatibility of twilio with our project, I've tried to search for Twilio phone number using NodeJS API but, it is throwing 404 error for all the locations every time. Is it the problem with trial account or code.

Here is my code

```js
var accountSid = '[My AccountSid]'; 
var authToken = '[My authToken]'; 
 
//require the Twilio module and create a REST client 
var client = require('../lib')('ACCOUNT_SID', 'AUTH_TOKEN');
 
client.availablePhoneNumbers('US').mobile.get({  
}, function(err, data) { 
    if(data){
    data.incomingPhoneNumbers.forEach(function(number) { 
  console.log(number.PhoneNumber); 
 }); 
    }else{
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am finding that too right now. Trying to discover why.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Ruby `client.incoming_phone_numbers('US').fetch` raises the same error irrespective of the country I select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We don't actually have a distinction between mobile and local numbers in the US, since the number format is the same and all numbers are voice and SMS capable.

So, I'd just use `.local` instead of `.mobile`.

Let me know if that helps.

**[EDIT]**

I used the following code and it returned and printed a list of US local numbers:

```
var twilio = require("twilio");
var client = new twilio(process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

client.availablePhoneNumbers('US').local.get({},
  function(err, data) { 
    console.log(data);
  }
)
```

Comment: '{ status: 404,
  message: 'The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/AvailablePhoneNumbers/US/Local.json was not found',
  code: 20404,
  moreInfo: 'https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20404' }'

Comment: Phil I dont see much change in in the result after changing the Code.

Comment: I've added the code I've tested with. If that message was copied directly, you may not be setting your Account SID correctly, as it should say your actual ACCOUNT_SID in the URL, not just the string "ACCOUNT_SID".